# Remove "Login with email" from Dex WebUI

Tags: kubernetes, ldap, coreos, openid-connect

I have been using CoreOS Dex to integretae my K8s apps with LDAP.
I have configured only LDAP as one of connectors whereas while redirecting it to Dex, I get an option as below:

[image] to login with email or ldap which is misleading.
Since email authentication won't work.

Is there any way I can remove the email authentication from Dex UI ?

Answer (score 3):

With little more digging, I found out that I had enabled the enabledPasswordDB option as true. I believe with this parameter dex tries to look for some local email addresses to login. Once we make that to false we are able to login.

Comment: We had the exact same problem (most likely after copying some example we found). And for clarity, the option is called `enablePasswordDB`. Removing it resolved the issue.